# Inconsistent behavior of map function with Empty value in Supply and plain Array?

Tags: swift, raku, combine

Recently, I have been learning Swift's Combine framework.

In Apple's words:

> The Combine framework provides a declarative approach for how your app
> processes events. Rather than potentially implementing multiple
> delegate callbacks or completion handler closures, you can create a
> single processing chain for a given event source. Each part of the
> chain is a Combine operator that performs a distinct action on the
> elements received from the previous step.

In Combine, There is a function called `compactMap`, which can filter nil values:

```swift
import Combine

let strings = ["a", "1.24", "3", "def", "45", "0.23"].publisher

strings
  .compactMap { Float($0) }
  .sink(receiveValue: {
    print($0)
  })
  .store(in: &subscriptions)
)
```

[image: compactMap in Swift]

I rewrite the above code in Raku as the following:

```perl
my @strings = ["a", "1.24", "3", "def", "45", "0.23"];
my Supply $supply = Supply.from-list(@strings);
my Supply $compact = $supply.map(-> $value {
  try { Num($value) }
  if $! { Empty } else { Num($value) }
 }); # .grep(Num);

$compact.tap(
    &say,
    done => { say 'finished' },
    quit => { say 'done'     }
);

# ()   <--
# 1.24
# 3
# ()   <--
# 45
# 0.23
```

But it also output two empty parentheses. When use map on plain Array instead of on a Supply, the map with Empty value got filtered:

```perl
my @strings = ["a", "1.24", "3", "def", "45", "0.23"];

my @compacted = @strings.map(-> $value {
    try { Num($value) }
    if $! { Empty } else { Num($value) }
});

.say for @compacted;

# 1.24
# 3
# 45
# 0.23
```

Is the behavior of `map` function with **Empty** value in `Supply` and plain `Array` inconsistent?

Comment: I am confused - is this a question about Combine or Raku? You start with "I have been learning Swift's Combine framework" and also tagged "swift" and "combine", but the body of your question asks about something completely irrelevant to Swift or Combine (?).

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry for confusion, My question is about Raku. I use Raku's `Supply` to implement the same logic of Combine's `compactMap` operator, but found the Raku version is less elegant than Swift's Combine

Comment: I think it is worth making an issue about the inconsistency in handling `Empty` between `Supply` and `Array`.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen thanks for your attention, I will making an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not do it like this...

```
my @strings = ["a", "1.24", "3", "def", "45", "0.23"];

my $supply = Supply.from-list(@strings);
my $compact = $supply.grep(*.Num.so);
$compact.tap(&say);

# 1.24
# 3
# 45
# 0.23
```

I agree that there seems to be a small divergence (related to Failure handling) vs. regular grep (no .so needed)...

```
say @strings.grep(*.Num);
#(1.24 3 45 0.23)
```